# Can I hold git credentials in environment variables?

Tags: git, environment-variables

I'd like to create a very simple shell script, which will ultimately be called by another application, that updates a local git repository:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $1
sudo git pull
```

When executing this I'm asked for credentials (I'm pulling from a private BitBucket repository).

Can I ( briefly) store credentials in environment variables?

```
#!/bin/bash

export  GIT_USERNAME=<user>
export  GIT_PASSWORD=<pass>

cd $1
sudo git pull
```

The above doesn't work. Would anything? I could programmatically modify the origin url but that seems a bit execessive.

Comment: git doesn't use credentials, it relies on the transport being used. Are you using git over ssh? If so you should look at ssh keys.

Comment: `git` has a credentials system now, @CBBailey: [https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)

Answer (score 91):

I know that it's very old question but if you really need to pass username and password for HTTP basic authentication you can just set helper like this:

```
git config credential.helper '!f() { sleep 1; echo "username=${GIT_USER}"; echo "password=${GIT_PASSWORD}"; }; f'
```

UPDATE: I've added `sleep 1` to the function. In some environments it may be probably needed due to race condition. I've got 2 virtual machines running Debian Jessie. They had the same architecture but different CPU and different number of cores. On one of these machines the helper was working fine without `sleep`. On the other one it wasn't. After few hours of debugging I run `strace` to see what's happening. And it magically started to work. `strace` just made git a little bit slower.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine for HTTP-based pushes! For SSH I would also vote for keys though.

Comment: What does the use of the exclamation mark in `'!f()` do here? It seems this would be a reference to a previous command in history. Using `bash` to execute what is in the helper string as a plain command causes an error with this syntax anyway. I'm curious why it works.

Comment: N/m -- I see now this is unique to git, but I couldn't find it in the git documentation. The exclamation mark tells git to treat the string config option as executable shell code. For credential helper, for example, if it doesn't treat it as executable, then it tries to append the string to the 'credential' argument and follow it by other options specified in the string.

Comment: Git documentation to help explain how this works: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage

Comment: I had issues with the newline character not being echo'd consistently on different systems.  Using `printf` in place of `echo` is supposedly more reliable.

Comment: `-e` parameter to `echo` is missing to interpret `\n` correctly. Excellent answer otherwise.

Comment: I tried both and it didn't seem to work for whatever reason. This method seems to work https://alanedwardes.com/blog/posts/git-username-password-environment-variables/. Is there anything I might be overlooking?

Comment: Newline characters in the (`username`, `password`, etc.) keys and values are not allowed by `git-credential`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential#IOFMT

Comment: Yes, there does seem to be a timing issue.  The credential helper only worked intermittently for me until I inserted the sleep 1.

Comment: As a side note, even though the example in the documentation creates a function `f` and then calls it. You don't need to do that, you can just write this as: `'!echo "username=${USERNAME}"; echo "password=${PASSWORD}";'`

Comment: @Randy31: It's Greek to me

Comment: Is that right @PeterFrost? I was wondering why the h*ll they were doing that. Why would you invent all that declare a function and then call it if it wasn't necessary? Surely there's a reason? Maybe on some versions, or some providers, or some platforms, or something?

Answer (score 26):

You can set the username in the git config with:

```
git config credential.https://github.com.username $GIT_USER
```

Then you can set the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable to a script that will provide the password:

```
export GIT_ASKPASS=/path/to/git_env_password.sh
```

The contents of `git_env_password.sh` would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $GIT_PASSWORD
```

N.B: This will store the username in the git config, so if you are not okay with that use another solution.

For more info consult the [gitcredentials man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

Answer (score 17):

If you're only running one git command in your script you can make the config change extremely localised using the -c argument (scroll right to see the `pull` command).

```
git -c credential.helper='!f() { sleep 1; echo "username=${GIT_USER}"; echo "password=${GIT_PASSWORD}"; }; f' pull
```

(I would have commented on [patryk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1319367/patryk-%C5%9Aciborek) answer but lack the reputation points at time of writing)

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can pass you git Passwort/Username with env, using [git-credential-env](https://github.com/L33T-KR3W/git-credential-env/wiki)

```
GIT_USER=foo
GIT_PASS=bar
npm install -g git-credential-env
git config credential.helper "env --username=GIT_USER --password=GIT_PASS"
```

The wiki in this project says

```
You can accomplish the same behavior by using an inline bash function:
GIT_USER=foo
GIT_PASS=bar
git config credential.helper "!f() { echo \"username=${GIT_USER}\\npassword=${GIT_PASS}\"; }; f"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Environment variables *only* solution

The answers above are valid, but they rely on either setting a value in a config file, or specifying a config with `-c` for a single command.

But there is another way. You can specify the config itself with an environment variable, so multiple git processes will use it, but it won't be saved permanently to a config file.

My usecase is installing a private Python package from GitHub which depends on *another* private Python package as part of a deployment script. I have a GitHub App token with read-only access to both private repositories. I tried installing with:

```bash
pipx install git+https://x-access-token:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/org/example.git
```

This works for the first repository, but `pipx` and `git` don't know they should reuse the credentials for the dependency private repository.

### Specify custom credential helper with environment variables

The solution is to configure a custom git credential helper as described in other answers, but to specify it using the [GIT_CONFIG_KEY environment variables](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#ENVIRONMENT).

To do this, simply set the following environment variables:

```bash
export GITHUB_TOKEN=your-github-token-here
export GIT_CONFIG_COUNT=2
export GIT_CONFIG_KEY_0='credential.https://github.com.username'
export GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_0=x-access-token
export GIT_CONFIG_KEY_1='credential.https://github.com.helper'
export GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_1='!f() { test "$1" = get && echo "password=${GITHUB_TOKEN}"; }; f'
```

### Validate

To check that this is working as expected, run the following command, and confirm that there are no errors, and that the password field contains the exact expected value of your GITHUB_TOKEN:

```bash
$ echo -e 'protocol=https\nhost=github.com' | git credential fill
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=x-access-token
password=your-github-token-here
```

To confirm that git is using the environment configuration, run:

```bash
git config --get-regexp 'credential.*'
```

You should now be able to clone private git repositories without specifying GitHub App token in the URL, and all operations in the current shell environment should inherit the credentials:

```bash
pipx install git+https://github.com/org/example.git
```

**Note on caching**

Git appears to cache the credential, so if you need to change the `GITHUB_TOKEN`, you will need to first reject the cached value as follows:

```bash
echo -e 'protocol=https\nhost=github.com' | git credential reject
```

### Further reading

- [Git credential config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-credentiallturlgt)
- [Git custom credential helpers](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials/2.29.0#_custom_helpers)
- [Git credential helper examples](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage#_under_the_hood)