# Terraform cannot pull modules as part of jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I have a jenkinsfile that was working and able to deploy some infrastructure automatically with terraform. Unfortunately after adding a terraform module with a git source it stopped working with the following error:

```
+ terraform init -input=false -upgrade

Upgrading modules...

- module.logstash

  Updating source "git::https://bitbucket.org/*****"

Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: error downloading 'https://bitbucket.org/*****': /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into '.terraform/modules/34024e811e7ce0e58ceae615c545a1f8'...

fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.org': No such device or address



script returned exit code 1
```

The urls above were obfuscated after the fact. Below is the cut down module syntax:

```
module "logstash" {
  source             = "git::https://bitbucket.org/******"
  ...
}
```

Below is the Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'linux'
  }
  triggers {
    pollSCM('*/5 * * * *')
  }
  stages {
    stage ('init') {
      steps {
        sh 'terraform init -input=false -upgrade'
      }
    }
    stage('validate') {
      steps {
        sh 'terraform validate -var-file="production.tfvars"'
      }
    }
    stage('deploy') {
      when {
        branch 'master'
      }
      steps {
        sh 'terraform apply -auto-approve -input=false -var-file=production.tfvars'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I believe this to be a problem with terraform internally using git to checkout the module but Jenkins has not configured the git client within the pipeline job itself. Preferably I would be able to somehow pass the credentials used by the multibranch pipeline job into the job itself and configure git but I am at a loss of how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a public project?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR no it's not unfortunately. Both the parent project and module are private repos in bitbucket

Comment: This is a git issue and not a Terraform/Jenkins issue.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am aware that this is a git credential issue, however it is the act of passing the checkout credentials in from the Jenkins build which I am having trouble with, not configuring git itself which I could do manually.

Comment: i do not see any `withCredentials` in your pipeline code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found a non-ideal solution that requires you to specify the credentials inside your Jenkinsfile rather than automatically using the credentials used by the job for checkout.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'bitbucketcreds', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASS', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USER')]) {
  sh "git config --global credential.helper '!f() { sleep 1; echo \"username=${env.GIT_USER}\\npassword=${env.GIT_PASS}\"; }; f'"
  sh 'terraform init -input=false -upgrade'
  sh 'git config --global --remove-section credential'
}
```

The trick is to load the credentials into environment variables using the `withCredentials` block and then I used the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536732/can-i-hold-git-credentials-in-environment-variables) to set the credential helper for git to read in those creds. You can then run `terraform init` and it will pull down your modules. Finally it clears the modified git settings to hopefully avoid contaminating other builds. Note that the `--global` configuration here is probably not a good idea for most people but was required for me due to a quirk in our Jenkins agents.

If anyone has a smoother way of doing this I would be very interested in hearing it.