# Github 2FA forces me to regenerate personal access token when pushing

Tags: git, github, https, access-token, two-factor-authentication

So I set up my github with 2FA a little while ago, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950497/2fa-give-problems-when-pushing-to-github) initial solution to my problem of signing in with accesstoken over password. However, remembering this token is next to impossible - and storing it in txt is not safe. How do i circumvent this problem *without* changing from HTTPS to SSH?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're struggling to find an answer to this question is that SSH is the best (simplest and most secure) solution. What's stopping you from using it?

Alternatively, you can use the credentials helper, but standard usage will store your token in a text file.

If you're *really* desparate to do this, try hacking it with environment variables: [Can I hold git credentials in environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536732/can-i-hold-git-credentials-in-environment-variables)